# Integrals w.r.t. measure $A\mapsto \int_Agd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-additive complete measure*  defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of the sets of unit $X$.
If $g\in L^1(X,\mu)$ is a non-negative function, then, if I am not wrong, we can define a measure $\nu$ having the same characteristics by letting $$\nu (A):=\int_A g\,d\mu$$ for any $\mu$-measurable set $A\subset X$.

I wonder whether the identity $$\int_Xf\,d\nu=\int_X fg\,d\mu$$ holds true for some class of functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ somewhat less trivial than the constant or characteristic functions and, if it does, how can it be proved? I thank any answerer very much.

*Such are the conditions on the measure used to define the Lebesgue integral by A.N. Kolmogorov and S.V. Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа*, approximately equivalent to *Introductory real analysis*, which contains all that I know of Lebesgue integration and says nothing directly related to my question.

---

***EDIT*** (Jul 29 '16): I have been told by a gratuated student in mathematics that $\nu$ may not be complete and Kolmogorov-Fomin's does not define a Lebesgue integral for non-complete measures.

Comment: Yes that identity holds basically for every measure $\nu$ that is *absolutey continuous* with respect to $\mu$. $g$ is then called the "Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$.

Comment: Here is a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem

Comment: Oh, I see now that how asked for which $f$ that identity holds, not for which $\nu$. The answer is, if $g$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$, it holds for every measurable $f$, because the right-hand side is then basically just a different way to write the left-hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is true for characteristic functions, you can do a simple linearity argument to show it is true for all simple functions.  Then do an approximation argument to finish.

Comment: If $f:X\to[0,+\infty)$ is measurable , from W. Rudin, *Real and Complex Analysis*, § 1.17 (I've only followed Kolmogorov-Fomin's, but I learnt this theorem a few days ago by chance), we know that there are measurable $f_n: X\to[0,+\infty)$ taking a finite amount of values such that $$\forall x\in X f_1(x)\le f_2(x)\le\ldots\le f(x)\quad\land\quad f_n(x)\to f(x).$$

Comment: We also need Beppo Levi's theorem which guarantees that, if $\varphi_1(x)\le \varphi_2(x)\le\ldots$, with $\varphi_n\in L^1(X)$, and if $\exists K:\forall n\quad\int_X \varphi_nd\mu\le K$, then almost everywhere the limit $\lim_n \varphi_n(x)$ exists finite and $\lim_n\int_X \varphi_nd\mu=\int_X\lim_n \varphi_n d\mu$.

Comment: But, if $fg\in L^1(X,\mu)$, then $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad\int_X f_nd\nu=\int_X f_n gd\mu\le\int_X fgd\mu$$ (if $f\in L^1(X,\nu)$ then $\forall n\quad \int_X f_ngd\mu=\int_X f_n d\nu\le\int_X fd\nu$) and then (in both cases) $\{f_n\}$ and $\{f_ng\}$ satifsy the hypothesis of the sequence $\{\varphi_n\}$ of Levi's theorem. Therefore $$\lim_n\int_X f_nd\nu=\int_X\lim_nf_nd\nu=\int_X fd\nu$$$$=\lim_n\int_X f_ngd\mu=\int_X\lim_nf_ngd\mu=\int_X fgd\mu.$$

Comment: Then $fg\in L^1(X,\mu)\iff f\in L^1(X,\nu)$ and $\int_Xfd\nu=\int_Xfgd\mu$ hold for both the negative and positive part of $f$ and, therefore, for any $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, Am I right? I apologise if that appears to be trivial, but I have never seen that kind of proof in the only text about Lebesgue integration (Kolmogorov-Fomin's) that I've studied (by myself). Thank you so much!